# Run test based on defined priority with multiple classes through test.xml file

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have 3 classes for with 3 tests each.

Class 1

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
public void testA1() {
    System.out.println("testA1");
}

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void testA2() {
    System.out.println("testA2");
}

@Test( priority = 3 )
public void testA3() {
    System.out.println("testA3");
}
```

Class 2

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
public void testB1() {
    System.out.println("testB1");
}

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void testB2() {
    System.out.println("testB2");
}

@Test( priority = 3 )
public void testB3() {
    System.out.println("testB3");
}
```

Class 3

```
@Test( priority = 1 )
public void testC1() {
    System.out.println("testC1");
}

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void testC2() {
    System.out.println("testC2");
}

@Test( priority = 3 )
public void testC3() {
    System.out.println("testC3");
}
```

This is my XML file code.

```
<test verbose="2" name="hello" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="Class1"></class>
        <class name="Class2"></class>
        <class name="Class3"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Here is my Answer 
testA1
testB1
testC1
testA2
testB2
testC2
testA3
testB3
testC3

But my expected answer is 
testA1
testA2
testA3
testB1
testB2
testB3
testC1
testC2
testC3

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: how do you run your suite?

Comment: I am running through maven framework and directly in intellij, same error for both cases

Answer (score 1):

The seen behavior is the expected one.

In fact, `priority` is more important that `group-by-instances` ( https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L48)
and that's why TestNG respect `priority` instead of `group-by-instances`.

To achieve your expected behavior, you have to replace `priority` by a more important order feature, like `dependsOnMethods`:

```
@Test
public void testA1() {
    System.out.println("testA1");
}

@Test( dependsOnMethods = "testA1" )
public void testA2() {
    System.out.println("testA2");
}

@Test( dependsOnMethods = "testA2" )
public void testA3() {
    System.out.println("testA3");
}
```

---

As asked in the comments, if you really want a "priority on a class without a strong dependency", you can make it yourself with [a method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) where you can order methods as you want. In pseudo code, something like:

```
public class PriorityOnClassOrder implements IMethodInterceptor {

  public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    // 1. Group by instance/class
    Map<Class<?>, List<IMethodInstance>> map = ...
    for (IMethodInstance method : methods) {
      map.get(method.getInstance().getClass()).add(method);
    }

    List<IMethodInstance> result = ...
    // 2. Order methods from an instance/clas according to their priority
    for(Map.Entry entry : map.entries()) {
      List<IMethodInstance> m = entry.value();
      Collections.sort(m, new Comparator<IMethodInstance>() {
        public int compare(IMethodInstance o1, IMethodInstance o2) {
          return o1.getMethod().getPriority() - o2.getMethod().getPriority()
        }
      });
      result.addAll(m);
    }

    // 3. Return the result
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But i want to run independent tests. Depends on method will not work for me in this case. Is there any other way to sort it out with this priority numbers and xml file?

Comment: Nope. Remove priority in that case.

Comment: I have refer this link for same issue. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes".

Comment: can we have class priority higher which is higher that test priority? Please help me on this. I am stuck from so long

Comment: The answer from the other question worked before the change. You can an old TestNG version if you don't care about fixes. I will update my answer with a solution which can help you.

Comment: Yes actually i dont have any major issues with fixes. So i can use old version, i will try to update same in my code.

Comment: You can try the proposed solution if you can.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but it looks so complex to me. I am looking for some easy way to sort it out...

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed, priority flag affect for whole  not for single class. The easiest way is to jus increase priority level in second class.

```
@Test( priority = 4 )
public void testA1() {
    System.out.println("testA1");
}

@Test( priority = 5 )
public void testA2() {
    System.out.println("testA2");
}

@Test( priority = 6 )
public void testA3() {
    System.out.println("testA3");
}
```

Also you can put single class in single , i think it's even better if you want to separate tests domain.

```
 <test name="Test1" verbose="3" >
  <classes>
    <class name="tests.NewTest"></class>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Test2" verbose="3" >
   <classes>
    <class name="tests.NewTest2"></class>
  </classes>
  </test>
```

And `verbose` flag. I hardly recommend this during debugging.

Comment: In first case it will be really difficult for me to manage to give priority to every single test.. As total i will be having 400-500 Test cases. So this will not use for me.

Comment: Second case is much better to use. But I have one more option which i added here..

Comment: You said that you have 400-500 test cases, and in your case, the result which you publish below you will need to include all methods, one by one. Maybe you should think about resolve made programmatic. Just make TestNG object and add classes method etc. by XmlSuite, XmlClass, XmlTest, then aggregate it into main object.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution of problem.

Please refer below XML code for same.

```
<classes>
            <class name="Class1">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testA1" />
                    <include name="testA2" />
                    <include name="testA3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
           <class name="Class2">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testB1" />
                    <include name="testB2" />
                    <include name="testB3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="Class3">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testC1" />
                    <include name="testC2" />
                    <include name="testC3" />
                </methods>
            </class>
```

This will give you expected result. Plus it will be easier to manage also. As if we want to see my all tests or remove some tests, i can look into test.xml