# TestNG tests priority in multiple classes

Tags: java, testng

I have 2 calasses, every class has 2 tests:
Class A, Test 1 (priotity 1), test 2 (priority 2)
Class B, Test 1 (priotity 1), test 2 (priority 2)

when i execute my tests the order is:
A1
B1
A2
B2

i need it to run like this:
A1
A2
B1
B2

here is a thread with a similar issue, but this does't work for me.
I added group-by-instances="true"  but it does't work.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/priority-in-testng-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: First of all why do you need priorities in your tests? Do you actually need to split tests into 2 classes? Have you considered using dependsOn, like dependsOnMethods or dependsOnGroups?

Comment: I cannot place 1000 tests inside a single class... The way i do it is 3 to 20 test methods on every class. Dependsonmethods can work, but not what im looking for

Comment: Here is the solution, [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437975/run-test-based-on-defined-priority-with-multiple-classes-through-test-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `dependsOnMethods` instead of `priority` which is global for all the suite.

Comment: Ok, decided to use dependsOnMethods and it actually works as i need. Thanks

Comment: Update- dependaOnMethod is problematic. If the method before fails then the one after will fail due to error related to missing dependOnMethod.. so for now the only solution I have is to use method names according the abc. E.g A_method, B_method...

Comment: If the method before fails, the next ones are supposed to be skipped and not failed. And I don't understand your remark about missing "dependOnMethod".